# How to generate graphql schema on run time?

Tags: mongodb, go, graphql

I have a graphql server written in golang using graphql-go api which fetches data from MongoDb and sends the data to the user. But this is when the graphql schema is static. In the future if there is a new field added to a mongodb collection, and the user queries it, then graphql server should be able to fetch that field dynamically. That means, run time schema needs to be generated. The type of the field is unknown. How can this be achieved ?

Comment: It seems that the server should be able to be alerted of those new fields, and rebuild the `graphql.Schema` on those events...

Comment: @dolmen Mongodb doesn't support triggers or alerts which is a problem.

Comment: This is probably not a good use of graphql. Imagine that you have several documents with different fields or fields with the same name but different types. Graphql should be defining the type not the backend document